# can't show modal form in laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

i have a problem with the modal that won't show up.

here's the code of my index.blade.php of my modal.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#reportModal">
```

here's my modal in index.blade.php, i can't put all of my modal code in this because it isn't allowed.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="reportModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Tambah Data Siswa</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
```

and here's my  tag in master.blade.php

```
<body>
    <!-- WRAPPER -->
    <div id="wrapper">
        <!-- NAVBAR -->
        @include('layouts.includes._navbar')
        <!-- END NAVBAR -->
        <!-- LEFT SIDEBAR -->
        @include('layouts.includes._sidebar')
        <!-- END LEFT SIDEBAR -->
        <!-- MAIN -->
        @yield('content')
        <!-- END MAIN -->
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <footer>
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <p class="copyright">&copy; 2017 <a href="https://www.themeineed.com" target="_blank">Theme I Need</a>. All Rights Reserved.</p>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </div>
```

if you guys wanted more of my code, i can post it more in comments, any help will be appreciated, thanks guys.

Comment: What is not working and what error you have got?

Comment: it won't show modal when i press a button.

Comment: you can watch my video for full code you can resolve it. https://youtu.be/bLUqF8MI7Fk

Comment: Check the console,  any error there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using bootstrap modal use this:

```
       <!-- Button trigger modal --> 
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#reportModal"> Open Modal</button> 
    <!-- Modal --> 
    <div class="modal fade" id="reportModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"> 
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">     
   <div class="modal-content"> 
       <div class="modal-header"> 
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Tambah Data Siswa</h5>
     
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"> <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span> 
</button> 
</div> 
    <div class="modal-body"> ... </div> 
<div class="modal-footer"> 
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button> 
    </div> 
      </div> 
   </div> 
</div>
```

For more info check
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/